# mysql_insert_id and mysql_pconnect

Tags: php, mysql

I've been using mysql_pconnect to establish all DB connections on my PHP site, with the theory that it's more efficient (debatable, I know).

I went to use mysql_insert_id to get the ID from a recent INSERT and it occurred to me that given the multi-threaded nature of web requests, I can't guarantee that another PHP script using the same pconnection has made a DB INSERT before my call to mysql_insert_id.

This is kind of a huge deal as I see no other way to guarantee atomicity of the INSERT and ID retrieval, as the ID is not returned by the INSERT query (or I don't know how to get it).

So basically I can never use mysql_pconnect if I want to have thread-safe INSERTS and ID retrieval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_insert_id()` returns the last id within context of the current connection session. Thus avoiding race-condition problems. There's a bunch of notes/comments regarding this on the php.net manual for [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id)

More Info:

- [PHP/MySQL insert row then get 'id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id)
- [How bad is using SELECT MAX(id) in MYSQL instead of mysql_insert_id() in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511826/how-bad-is-using-select-maxid-in-mysql-instead-of-mysql-insert-id-in-php)
- [get id of last inserted record without using mysql_insert_id()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271230/get-id-of-last-inserted-record-without-using-mysql-insert-id)

This should be easy to test:

```
<?php
// connection already established
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES('foo', 'bar')");
sleep(15);
echo mysql_insert_id();
```

Then see if you can fool it by slamming it with requests during the sleep period.. and check the insert_id results.

Comment: I did the suggested test, and I found that a second script that inserted multiple rows into the table during the sleep(15) did not affect the returned value of mysql_insert_id() from the first script.  That's promising, but it's possible that mysql_pconnect just decided to create two separate connections instead of sharing them for these scripts.  I think I may be coming to the conclusion that Shashwat is correct--PHP will not re-use the same connection as long as any other script is running that is already using that connection.  But I can't find hard documentation that confirms this.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_pconnect means that the connection won't be closed from the php module to the mysql.As there is an overhead of creating a new connection so it can be beneficial if you are creating a lot of connections.

As php executes a request in a single thread.And most probably you will be using 1 connection to the database a call to INSERT and subsequent call to ID retrieval is gonna be ATOMIC.

The MYSQL connection taken by 1 php thread can't be used by another php thread while it is still being in used which ensure atomicity.

Comment: My concern is two separate PHP pages, both of them using mysql_pconnect (and therefore the same connection).  I'm skeptical of your assertion that 1 php thread must wait for another thread to close before it can use the same connection.  Though I would have to run tests to be sure.

Comment: @jpeskin: Two separate PHP pages can't use same connection.A connection is acquired.1 PHP page can have 2 connections but oppositi is not true..

Comment: it seems you may be right. My tests (see other answer) seem to support your theory.  I can't find any documentation on php.net's mysql_pconnect page to confirm this.  Do you know where this is documented?  Thanks.